# Android PatternSyntaxException

Tags: java, android, regex

The following regex doesn't work on Android 7.0 API 24, but it works on JDK.

```
Pattern P = Pattern.compile("^((\\n[ \\t\\x0B\\f]*}[ \\t\\x0B\\f]*)\\n).*", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

The exception I get on Android is the following:

```
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 22
    ^((\n[ \t\x0B\f]*}[ \t\x0B\f]*)\n).*
                          ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1340)
```

Comment: Try escaping the `}`.

Comment: [Your pattern works well](https://ideone.com/7xKbsF), but try escaping `}`, really.

Comment: Thanks!!! It's only escape with '}'.